# sorting efficiently

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

I have an array of values which is almost, but not quite sorted, with a few values displaced (say, 50 in 100000). How to sort it most efficiently?

Comment: you can add "algorithm" in your tag. Perhaps they can help too.

Comment: what are your values ? simple ints or floats, or structures ? What is your measure for efficiency ? space ? time ?

Comment: Dude, you seriously need to go back and review your questions and ACCEPT some.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under the assumption that the array is almost sorted, you could use one of the following :

### [Smoothsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothsort)

Wiki even has a java implementation on it. Since you can't do it faster than O(n) (since it takes that much time in order to even find out if an array is sorted or not) smoothsort is a good choice. More details [here](http://www.keithschwarz.com/smoothsort/).

> The advantage of smoothsort is that it
>   comes closer to O(n) time if the input
>   is already sorted to some degree

### [Coctail sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocktail_sort)

> The complexity of cocktail sort in big
>   O notation is O(n2) for both the worst
>   case and the average case, but it
>   becomes closer to O(n) if the list is
>   mostly ordered before applying the
>   sorting algorithm,

### [Timsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort)

Java's arrays are actually now using timsort in java 7 in order to sort objects (`sort()`). Description of timsort [here](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/listsort.txt).

Answer (score 1):

Use [insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort#Best.2C_worst.2C_and_average_cases); it's great with almost-sorted arrays, since it's near O(n) time for them. I actually believe the .NET Framework uses insertion sort for sorting enum values internally (since they're often sorted), though I'd have to re-check that.

Answer (score 0):

My first intuition would be to identify the misplaced elements and move them to a separate array, sort them there with whatever algorithm you like (with that few, it shouldn't matter), then merge sort them back in.

Comment: Finding out the "degree" of unsorted-ness (and hence the "misplaced" elements) in an array is actually hard, as far as I know... do you know of any good algorithm for that?

Comment: Please propose an algorithm for finding what you call "misplaced elements." Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finding **the best algorithm for sorting depends on** how much control you have over the data.

Sorting algorithms are classified into methods of insertion, exchange, selection, merging, etc.. This means that if you can control the mechanism that inserts new data on the array, you can sort them while doing that. If you can only sort the array after the data is there, then the best algorithm for doing that is another one completely different.

Anyway, these are interesting readings:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm

[**what-should-students-be-taught-first-when-first-learning-sorting-algorithms**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212039/what-should-students-be-taught-first-when-first-learning-sorting-algorithms/212095#212095)

[**comparison-of-sorting-algorithms**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514841/comparison-of-sorting-algorithms/2514992#2514992)

[**what-is-the-fastest-sorting-algorithm-in-c**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753278/what-is-the-fastest-sorting-algorithm-in-c/1753304#1753304)

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, the `qsort` or `mergesort` functions provided by most libc implementations already handle this special case in an efficient manner.

So, read your libc documentation or even better, check how it implements sorting (if you have access to the source), because sometimes this is an implementation detail not estated on the docs!